# Why doi package does not function on TRB overleaf template?

Tags: overleaf

I added `\usepackage{doi}` after hyperref package in the [TRB template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/transportation-research-board-trb-latex-template/jkfndnnkkksw) but seems not functioning. Why does doi package work on some templates and does not on some others?

I have the below MWE.

```
\documentclass[numbered]{trbunofficial}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{moreverb,url}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{doi}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Abstract}
We will have max 200 words abstract here.

\hfill\break%
\noindent\textit{Keywords}: Blah blah
\newpage


\section{Introduction}
Let me cite this guy here \cite{theguy}.

\bibliographystyle{trb}
\bibliography{trb_template}

\end{document}
```

Assume I have a bib file named trb_template.bib with the below entry:

```
@article{theguy,
  title={What a great work he has done!},
  author={Guy, The},
  journal={Top Journal},
  volume={1},
  pages={1--10},
  year={2022},
  doi = {12.2022/jrnl.abbr.2022.01.01}
}
```

Comment: it is very hard to help if you just have external links and say "seems not functioning"  show the exact error that you get, and preferably add to your question a small but complete document that generates the error

Comment: I do not get an error. It just does not work at all. I will add an MWE.

Comment: I get an error (wholly unrelated to DOIs) with your MWE and the template files on Overleaf: `LATEX ERROR: NO \title GIVEN.` (https://www.overleaf.com/read/mrpwzhqnwymd) But aside from that error, the `\doi` command works fine when I add one to the text. If you are expecting the DOI from your .bib file to be printed in the references list, this is only done if the .bst file says to print it, and trb.bst does not contain any code to handle or print DOIs. This doesn't have anything to do with Overleaf specifically, it's part of the .bst file itself.

Comment: I meant it does not show up in the references section. I wonder what needs to be added into the trb.bst so that it does.